# Writing to file inside package Java

Tags: java, eclipse, file, stream

Hi I am new to Java, so kindly bear me.
I am reading info from a file and want to write to it.I am using eclipse.

My directory structure is

`ProjectName-->src-->Package` (This is my package where my java files are)

I am trying to create a jar file. My text file is inside the package.

To read from file i am using below code.

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("BookingInfo.csv");
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
br = new BufferedReader(isr);
```

Now i want to write to same file.I am doing something like this

```
String filename ="src/Package/BookingInfo.csv";    
File myFile = new File(filename);  
fw = new FileWriter(myFile,true);
fw.write(report);
fw.close();
```

But somehow its not updating it. Can you kindly adivise me on this.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to write back into the .jar file, unfortunately. You can write instead to a file in the filesystem, but the .jar will be immutable.

You *could* unpack the .jar programmatically (into a temp directory), overwrite the file and then rebuild the .jar file. See the [documentation on the .jar-related APIs.](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/apiindex.html)

Comment: Hi Brian,I haven't created the jar file yet,that is my final aim.Can't i even write back to a text file in package.

Comment: You cannot write back to the jar, nor should you try. Your application state should be kept separate from your application binary. Use a system property or an environment variable to tell your application about the data directory.

Comment: Hi Konstantion,Can't i even write back to a text file in package.

Comment: The type of file doesn't matter. You cannot write into the jar-packaged application.

Answer (score 1):

Your project's workspace files are not syncronized automatically, so you have to refresh in Eclipse. Than you will see the changes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give full path while creating a new file inside a project. Try this code:

File xmlFile = new File("src/com/company/project/xml/tags.xml");

And you will be able to create file in com.company.project.xml package.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
String url = getClass().getResource("BookingInfo.csv").getFile();
fw = new FileWriter(url ,true);
fw.write(report);
fw.close();
```

Comment: This doesn't work out of the box. You will get NPE in first line.

Comment: Make sure the `BookingInfo.csv` is in the directory of this class